# Download the source code in html of a form generated with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible by angularjs download a piece of code generated by a form?

Add a simple code:
http://jsbin.com/nufixiwali/edit?html,js,output

I would generate an .html to download only the code generated after the html tag.

Thank you

Comment: Hi maestro, where's your code? Please add it to the post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly, but you can retrieve the 'current' HTML for a given page in plain JavaScript with *document.body.innerHTML* (no matter how it has been generated). Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
function downloadAsFile(filename, type, data) {
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
downloadAsFile('myfile.html', 'text/html', myData)
```