# How to build a custom, downloadable file using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, download

I want to make a simple HTML page that takes some information from the user, then provides a downloadable file that contains that information. I have the form laid out, as well as JavaScript that creates the string that ideally would become the contents of the file, but **I don't know how to get HTML to create the file to download.**

I wouldn't be surprised if this question's been asked before, but I've looked and the only thing I can find is 'creating your first webpage' and the like. Please provide me with a link if this has been asked.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589570/download-the-source-code-in-html-of-a-form-generated-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
    window.open('data:text/html;base64,aGVsbG8=')
```

You just need to add a base64 encoded html string there, to encode it use function btoa('content'). You can also set a string to a link like:

```
    <a href="data:text/html;base64,aGVsbG8=">Download</a>
```